# SQL Compare Table1.Column1 to all values in Table2.Column2

Tags: sql

I have a table:
oCode that contains a 15 digit code, and a boolean flag.

I have a secondary table:
pCode that contains a list of 9 digit codes.

I need to update a stored procedure that will take the first 9 digits of the 15 digit code in oCode, and if those 9 digits equal any code found in pCode, I need to set the boolean flag to true.

I have tried many different ways and have not been successful, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help you…

```
WHERE left(oCode.code,9) in 
    (select pCode.code from pCode)
```